# oracle-mysql fast refresh materialized view

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-12c, materialized-view

Is is possible to Create Fast refresh enabled Materialized view from MySQL to Oracle .  i know steps for oracle to oracle Fast refresh enabled Materialized view. But now the scenario is need to transfer number of records from MySQL to oracle via db-link with use of materialized view. But every time i need to make Complete Refresh which is time consuming.
so is it possible to create fast refresh materialized view for MySQL to Oracle ?

Comment: [_This_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) discusses the 'best' ways to do Materialized Views in MySQL.  But, as you already know, the work must be done by the user.  I don't think any of them correspond to a Fast Refresh MV.  But they _might_ be "good enough"?

Answer (score 1):

A fast refresh requires (among many other things) materialized view logs on source tables.

[Refresh types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REPLN/repmview.htm#i29858)

> You can perform fast refreshes of materialized views only when the
>   master table or master materialized view has a materialized view log.

[image]

That functionality is specific to and implemented in Oracle, and not available in MySQL. It is not like no other database can provide the logically similar functionality, but this is the Oracle implementation, that works with Oracle databases.

Comment: ok any alternatives for this  which can reduce time consuming ?